# Android webrtc - Invalid transport parameter in ICE URI

Tags: android, webrtc, turn

I have deployed the server for streaming
https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc/blob/master/README.md

This is the Android app:
https://github.com/appsroxcom/WebRTCAndroid

If I connect with different browsers, it works but the Android app is crashing.
The Android app doesn't seem to create the PeerConnection.
The error is :
2021-10-16 19:11:02.802 9157-9459/com.example.webrtc.android A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 9459 (pool-1-thread-1)

I have seen that the reason for this error is this:
2021-10-16 18:47:49.341 32549-32605/com.example.webrtc.android W/ice_server_parsing.cc: (line 182): Invalid transport parameter in ICE URI: ["turn:mydomain.com:3478"]

I do not know how to fix this for Android. I tried different configurations for turn including those with ?transport

```
"urls": [
  "turn:hostnameForYourTurnServer:19305?transport=udp",
  "turn:hostnameForYourTurnServer:19305?transport=tcp"
],
```

What should I do?

THanks

Comment: The error looks like this if I include the transport parameter:
2021-10-16 19:27:38.922 14941-15478/com.example.webrtc.android W/ice_server_parsing.cc: (line 182): Invalid transport parameter in ICE URI: ["turn:mydomain.com:3478?transport=udp","turn:mydomain.com:3478?transport=tcp"]

Comment: even with the google url I get an error :
Invalid transport parameter in ICE URI: ["stun:turn2.l.google.com"]

Comment: If I specify the url with the ?transport parameter I get another error:
"Transport parameter should always be udp or tcp."

Comment: It seems that these errors are from the C++ library - as if it can not process the uri 
https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/trunk/webrtc/+/f54860e9ef0b68e182a01edc994626d21961bc4b/pc/iceserverparsing.cc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in [apprtc](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc) src/app_engine/constants.py, urls is a json array

```
# ICE_SERVER_OVERRIDE  = [
#   {
#     "urls": [
#       "turn:hostname/IpToTurnServer:19305?transport=udp",
#       "turn:hostname/IpToTurnServer:19305?transport=tcp"
#     ],
#     "username": "TurnServerUsername",
#     "credential": "TurnServerCredentials"
#   },
#   {
#     "urls": [
#       "stun:hostname/IpToStunServer:19302"
#     ]
#   }
# ]
```

but the android app treat it as a json string [here](https://github.com/appsroxcom/WebRTCAndroid/blob/master/webrtc/src/main/java/org/appspot/apprtc/RoomParametersFetcher.java#L209)

```
String url = server.getString("urls");
```

so you should change android code to

```
private List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServersFromPCConfigJSON(String pcConfig)
      throws JSONException {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(pcConfig);
    JSONArray servers = json.getJSONArray("iceServers");
    List<PeerConnection.IceServer> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < servers.length(); ++i) {
      JSONObject server = servers.getJSONObject(i);
      JSONArray urls = server.getJSONArray("urls");
      String username = server.has("username") ? server.getString("username") : "";
      String credential = server.has("credential") ? server.getString("credential") : "";
      for (int j = 0; j < urls.length(); ++j) {
        String url = urls.getString(j);
        PeerConnection.IceServer turnServer =
                PeerConnection.IceServer.builder(url)
                        .setUsername(username)
                        .setPassword(credential)
                        .createIceServer();
        ret.add(turnServer);
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }
```